# how to load a file from folder to memory stream buffer

Tags: vb.net

I am working on vb.net win form. My task is display the file names from a folder onto gridview control. when user clicks process button in my UI, all the file names present in gridview, the corresponding file has to be loaded onto memory stream buffer one after another and append the titles to the content of the file and save it in hard drive with _ed as a suffix to the file name.

I am very basic programmer. I have done the following attempt and succeeded in displaying filenames onto gridview. But no idea of later part. Any suggestions please?

'Displaying files from a folder onto a gridview

```
    Dim inqueuePath As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\INQUEUE"
    Dim fileInfo() As String
    Dim rowint As Integer = 0
    Dim name As String
    Dim directoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(inqueuePath)
    fileInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(inqueuePath)

    With Gridview1
        .Columns.Add("Column 0", "FileName")
        .AutoResizeColumns()
    End With

    For Each name In fileInfo
        Gridview1.Rows.Add()
        Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name)
        Gridview1.Item(0, rowint).Value = filename
        rowint = rowint + 1
    Next
```

Thank you very much for spending your valuable time to read this post.

Comment: [Here is a straightforward example](http://www.nonhostile.com/page-loading-file-steam-into-memory-stream.asp) of how to do what you need. There's two functions provided. One of them works if you have a filename and path, the other one works if you've already opened the file with [File.Open()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx). It's not an ideal example because it doesn't properly account for errors, but the basics of how you read a file are displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to read a file into a memorystream is quite easy, just have a look at the following example and you should be able to convert it to suite your needs:

```
    Dim bData As Byte()
    Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(Path))
    bData = br.ReadBytes(br.BaseStream.Length)
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bData, 0, bData.Length)
    ms.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length)
```

then just use the MemoryStream ms as you please. Just to clearify `Path` holds the full path and filename you want to read into your memorystream.