# how to load a file into memory stream

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a filename pointing to a text file, including its path, as a string. Now I'd like to load this `.csv` file into memory stream. How should I do that?

For example, I have this:

```
Dim filename as string="C:\Users\Desktop\abc.csv"
```

Comment: Pretty similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200329/how-to-load-a-file-from-folder-to-memory-stream-buffer

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You don't need to load a file into a MemoryStream.

You can simply call `File.OpenRead` to get a `FileStream` containing the file.

If you really want the file to be in a MemoryStream, you can call `CopyTo` to copy the FileStream to a MemoryStream.

Comment: can i append the file while itis in filestream?

Comment: @Ram: Yes, you can.  Just call `Open` rather than `OpenRead`.   You can then write and read the same stream.

Comment: CopyTo method exists from .NET 4 onwards. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5730893/1589759

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer, it's not what the op asked.

Answer (score 99):

```
Dim stream As New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename))
```

Comment: after loading a file into memory stream can i add titles to the content of the file? like headers in xls file.

Comment: This is the way. Not sure about the answer underneath this one as it doesn't answer the question asked

Answer (score 0):

I had an XML file being read from disk, using the old XmlReader API.  How to read the XML file into memory, and then work with it in memory, instead of reading the disk repeatedly?  Based on VB answer from Centro (upvoted) but with a Using block, and in C#.

The key line:

```
MemoryStream myXMLDocument = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\temp\myDemoXMLDocument.xml"));
```

Re the OP's question, if you wanted to load a CSV file into a MemoryStream:

```
MemoryStream myCSVDataInMemory = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Desktop\abc.csv"));
```

Following is a code snippet showing code to reads through XML document now that it's in a MemoryStream. Basically the same code as when it was coming from a FileStream that pointed to a file on disk. Yes, the XMLTextReader API is old and clunky, but it's what I had to work with in this app.

```
    string myXMLFileName = @"c:\temp\myDemoXMLDocument.xml";
    using (MemoryStream myXMLDocument = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(myXMLFileName)))
    {
            myXMLTextReader = new XmlTextReader(myXMLDocument);
            myXMLTextReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
            myXmlTextReader.Read(); // read the XML declaration node, advance to <Batch> tag
            while (!myXmlTextReader.EOF) 
            {
                if (myXmlTextReader.Name == "xml" && !myXmlTextReader.IsStartElement()) break;
                // advance to <Batch> tag
                while (myXmlTextReader.Name == "Batch" && myXmlTextReader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    string BatchIdentifier = myXmlTextReader.GetAttribute("BatchIdentifier");
                    myXmlTextReader.Read(); // advance to next tag
                    while (!myXmlTextReader.EOF)
                    {
                        if (myXmlTextReader.Name == "Transaction" && myXmlTextReader.IsStartElement())
                        {
                            // Start a new set of items
                            string transactionID = myXmlTextReader.GetAttribute("ID");
                        myXmlTextReader.Read(); // Read next element, possibly another Transaction tag
                    }
                }
                //All Batch tags are completed.Move to next tag
                myXmlTextReader.Read();
            }
            // Close the XML memory stream.
            myXmlTextReader.Close();
            myXmlDocument.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can copy it to a file stream like so:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open);
Image image = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
//Close File Stream
fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: Doing it this way will decompress the image then recompress it as jpeg. Just use the file stream copyto method to copy the byte array to the memory stream.