# Save picture directly to stream?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save a picture to database:

I am getting an error on this line:

```
Dim stream As New MemoryStream()

PictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

Is there a direct way to save a picture to memory stream without having to put it in picture box and then save it to the memory stream from the picture box?

Comment: what error, exactly?

Comment: "Is there a direct way"...well where is the picture data coming from originally? that isn't clear.

Comment: There error is: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
And for the picture I only specified its location for example: C:Users/.....

Comment: @KGD That probably means that `PictureBox1.Image` is null (A.K.A `Nothing`). If the PictureBox doesn't have an image, well, it's pretty obvious then, I guess. If, on the other hand, you _think_ the PictureBox has an image, you need to show us how you loaded the image into the PictureBox. That's because there are a few cases where you can see  an image on the PictureBox but it's actually null (e.g., disposed or not loaded the first place).

Comment: @KGD are you sure that you're setting the Image's Image property and not the BackgroundImage property?

Comment: [Fie.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes)

Comment: I just load it by: PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\Users\...\test.png" Is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: If so let me know the correct way to load it

Comment: For example, does this answer your question? [how to load a file into memory stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213993/how-to-load-a-file-into-memory-stream)

Comment: I manage to screen capture what I did. Can you advise me what is wrong in it. Is it the loading of the picture to the picture box or something else. http://prntscr.com/sj8z41

Comment: @ADyson I dont think this is the thing I need

Comment: why not? It shows you how to load data directly from a file into a memorystream. Isn't that what you asked for? I was thinking of the last answer specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6214032/5947043

Comment: I manage it to work. Thanks!